# Pandas read_sql duplicating columns when using both index_col and columns parameters

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I've got a SQLite database with the table `test_data` whose columns are:

| `date` | `id` | `kpi` | `value` | `run_datetime` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

I'm using the `read_sql` function to read in this table, keep only the first 4 columns, and set the first 3 as an index. To do this, I've called the `read_sql` function in the following way:

```
conn = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///test.db')
data = pd.read_sql(
    sql='test_data',
    con=conn,
    columns=['date', 'id', 'kpi', 'value'],
    index_col=['date', 'id', 'kpi']
)
```

However, this returns the following:

|  |  |  | date__1 | id__1 | kpi__1 | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **date** | **id** | **kpi** |  |  |  |  |
| 2021-05-01 | 0001 | kpi_1 | 2021-05-01 | 0001 | kpi_1 | 100 |
|  |  | kpi_2 | 2021-05-01 | 0001 | kpi_2 | 200 |
|  |  | kpi_3 | 2021-05-01 | 0001 | kpi_3 | 300 |

This keeps the columns that I want, but it duplicates the 3 I want in the index rather than converting them into the index like I'd expect. I get the same output if I explicitly use the `read_sql_table` function instead.

So, my questions are...

- **Is this behaviour expected, or do I have a malformed query?**
- **If this is a malformed query, how can I fix it?**

I can work around this by only using one of the arguments and applying the logic for the other on the DataFrame itself (e.g. only keeping the columns and then calling the `set_index` method) or by writing the SELECT query explicitly, so I'm *not* asking for an alternative solution.

---

## MWE

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy


def make_data(connection):
    pd.DataFrame(
        data=[
            ['2021-05-01', '0001', 'kpi_1', 100,  '2021-05-01 09:00'],
            ['2021-05-01', '0001', 'kpi_2', 200,  '2021-05-01 09:00'],
            ['2021-05-01', '0001', 'kpi_3', 300,  '2021-05-01 09:00']
        ],
        columns=['date', 'id', 'kpi', 'value', 'run_datetime']
    ).to_sql(
        name='test_data',
        con=connection,
        if_exists='replace',
        index=False
    )


def main():
    conn = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///test.db')
    make_data(conn)

    data = pd.read_sql(
        sql='test_data',
        con=conn,
        columns=['date', 'id', 'kpi', 'value'],
        index_col=['date', 'id', 'kpi']
    )
    print(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: But what the desired result you want?
Assuming you would like the index of 3 columns and 'value' being the only actual column, why don't you just use `columns=["value"],`. Index columns will be properly queried.

Comment: @van That fixed it, thank you! I had it in mind that the `column`s specified the columns from the _database_ that should be kept, not what should be a column in the DataFrame, and that the `index_col`s would repeat the columns that should be in the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per van's comment, this was a malformed query -- the columns for the index (`index_col`) should be distinct to the columns for the DataFrame (`columns`), so the working query is

```
conn = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///test.db')
data = pd.read_sql(
    sql='test_data',
    con=conn,
    columns=['value'],
    index_col=['date', 'id', 'kpi']
)
```